# Populate on embeded documents

Tags: mongoose, populate

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but I'll give it a try.

This is a simplified version of my schema

```
var mediaSchema = new Schema({
  remote_url: {type: String},
  media_type: {type: String, enum: ['jpg','png']},
  media_version: {type: String},
  public_id: {type:String},
  resource_type: {type: String},
  bytes: {type: Number}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Media', mediaSchema);

var User = new Schema({
  ....
  pictures: [Media.schema],
  sorted_pictures: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Media' }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

I am embedding the Media document in a User document. I also have a sorted array of ObjectIds on the embedded documents in order to support client-defined sorting

I am trying to query the following using:

```
User.findById(req.user, {sorted_pictures:1})
  .populate({path:'sorted_pictures', model: 'Media'})
  .exec(....
```

But I am getting an empty array as a result.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What would you like to achieve with `{sorted_pictures:1}`?

Comment: I am just filtering fields with {sorted_pictures:1}

Comment: Are you sure that this is working? the [Api](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) suggests that you cannot filter in the projection argument. You might want to use `findOne` and add the two selections therein

Comment: That part is working as expected. Even if I remove the projection, the result is still the same. I get an empty array on 'sorted_pictures'.

Comment: Ok then try to remove the `model: 'Media'` from the populate path